# how to add the IP address instead of being a localhost in selfsigned https webserver C#

Tags: c#, ssl, https

how to add the IP address instead of being localhost in self-signed https webserver in C#

I tried to set up the https via following article https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/develop-locally-with-https-self-signed-certificates-and-asp-net-core
And its working fine in localhost. that means working in 
https://localhost:44321

if I try to add the IP for example https://192.168.0.10:44321  (static IP of server) ; I can't access my server from the server itself or other systems in the local network.

Environment is Linux

Comment: have you tried the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file?

Comment: no, im working in Linux

Comment: Normally with certs you deal with names of the server, so you need to check what IP you are trying to connect on and what DNS name is associated with it

Comment: *I can't access my server from the server itself or other systems in the local network* kind of weird, can you double check that the application is running and opens port on 44321? you can use [netstat](https://askubuntu.com/a/538233/403728) for it. and check if your firewall allows access even from localhost. and do double check if you configure your kestrel to listen to all ipv4 not only `127.0.0.1`, see [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.0) - that `options.Listen` in the link you gave, should be `ListenAnyIP` i think.

Comment: i tried all these.But still not working

Comment: @ Bagus Tesa
port is listing in 44321.its working perfectly while using localhost.
when i give ip address server is not responding (192.168.0.10) refused to connect.
Netstat result 
tcp        0      0 localhost:44321         *:*                     LISTEN      -

Comment: options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 44321, listenOptions => is missing part for me 
its working now

Answer (score 0):

The `-DnsName` parameter of the `New-SelfSignedCertificate` cmdlet allows you to provide an array of host names. Don't include IP addresses in the certificate, instead you may include your $env:COMPUTERNAME or other strings that identify your server (maybe using the * wildcard).

Also, "localhost" is usually resolved to the IPv4 address 127.0.0.1/8 and IPv6 ::1/128, but your $HOSTNAME/COMPUTERNAME would be resolved to a public or LAN address like your 192.168.0.10; you need to bind your web server to all the addresses where it listen for requests (for instance using `https://*:44321` as the base address).

Comment: options.Listen(IPAddress.Any)
this is part i missed it..now its working